# Mobile Responsiveness with Google Web Designer

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, google-web-designer

So I used Google Web Designer for my site (*) and while I was able to make the entire site responsive, the animation in my header works great only on my desktop (which is where I designed the animation) - unfortunately GWD does not allow for any type of responsive building into animations. So my question is:

1. Does anyone know JS quiet well and can help point me in the right direction to getting this animation to scale down when the width of the page decreases?

OR

2. Know of any other solutions whereby I can apply a {display:none} to the desktop animation and plug-in a good counterpart for mobile?

Thank you for your time,

Byron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so in the interest of time, the solution I have settled on is to create 4 more animations, each with their own stage dimensions. I will be calling them to display:inline or display: none through the CSS depending on the users browser width (i.e. the standard @media screen css).